# Play/Scala 2.5 SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder"

Tags: scala, playframework, logback

I'm getting the following error after upgrading the Scala project from Play Framwork 2.4 to 2.5:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: play.api.Logger$.init(Ljava/io/File;Lscala/Enumeration$Value;)V
```

According to these pages:

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/Migration25#change-to-logback-configuration
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/SettingsLogger

I've updated the `logback.xml` file to use `play.api.libs.logback.ColoredLevel`. The page shows example of how to use other logging frameworks, but I wish to continue using the default logback framework. The documentation doesn't say any additional dependencies are required.

Am I missing some dependencies? What do I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missed one config file during the upgrade, update the Play version number in project/plugins.sbt to upgrade Play:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.5.x")
```

See https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/Migration25